# Accessing input$values from the UI of one R Shiny module with the server function of a second module

Tags: r, shiny

### 1. My objective

I want to use Shiny modules to create an app where:

1. a category A, B or C is selected using `radioButtons`
2. a `dateRangeInput` whose `min` and `max` arguments are determined by the selected category using `updateDateRangeInput`
3. subset a vector of dates so that it only contains elements between `start` and `end` of `dateRangeInput`

So far I've got steps 1. and 2. to work using a Shiny module. 
I prefer to have step 3. in a separate module or at least a separate module server function (see part 4).

My real use case involves reading a number of files from a directory into the Shiny app.
All files have a datestring and a category string as a part of their file name. 
Only files of the selected category and date within the date range should be read into my Shiny app.
In this minimal example, assume the files are represented by `all_dates`.
Note that in my real application I'm using R flexdashboard instead of a Shiny app in a script.

### 2. My code

Here is the first module UI function:

```r
library(shiny)

# date range depends on the selected category A, B or C
dateRangeCategoryUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    dateRangeInput(ns("date_range"), label = "select dates"),
    radioButtons(
      ns("category"), 
      label = "select category",
      choices = list("A", "B", "C"), 
      selected = "A"
    )
  )
}
```

Here is the first module server function:

```r
# Server function to find min and max date for a selected category
dateRangeCategory <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    category_min <- switch(
      input$category,
      "A" = Sys.Date() - lubridate::days(1),
      "B" = Sys.Date() - lubridate::days(2),
      "C" = Sys.Date() - lubridate::days(3)
    )
  category_max <- switch(
      input$category,
      "A" = Sys.Date() + lubridate::days(1),
      "B" = Sys.Date() + lubridate::days(2),
      "C" = Sys.Date() + lubridate::days(3)
    )
    updateDateRangeInput(
      session, 
      "date_range",
      start = Sys.Date(),
      end = Sys.Date(),
      min = category_min,
      max = category_max 
    )
  })
}
```

Here is the Shiny app using the above module that works as expected:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeCategoryUI("range_and_category")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(dateRangeCategory, "range_and_category")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For step 3. above I want to create a second module (in a different .R script) that:

1. accesses the `start` and `end` values of `dateRangeInput` created by `dateRangeCategoryUI`
2. loads a vector of dates (in this minimal example I simply create an object `all_dates`)
3. returns a subset of this object called `selected_dates` by only keeping dates within `start` and `end`

The second module server function could look something like this:

```r
selectDates <- function(input, output, session) {
  all_dates <- seq.Date(
    from = Sys.Date() - lubridate::days(3),
    to = Sys.Date() + lubridate::days(3),
    by = "days"
  )

  selected_dates <- reactive({
    # input$date_range should refer to `dateRangeInput` from `dateRangeCategoryUI`
    range_start <- input$date_range[1]
    range_end <- input$date_range[2]
    all_dates[all_dates >= range_start & all_dates <= range_start]
  })
  return(selected_dates)
}
```

I would then like to have these `selected_dates` in my the server function of my Shiny app:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeCategoryUI("range_and_category")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(dateRangeCategory, "range_and_category")  # first module
  selected_dates <- callModule(selectDates, "range_and_category")  # second module
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### 3. My main question

How can `selectDates` access the `start` and `end` values from `dateRangeInput` created by `dateRangeCategoryUI`?

### 4. Questions about module organization

1. If I choose to work with two modules, the second module will only have a server function and no UI function. Is that allowed?
2. Would it be easier to access `start` and `end` if I put the function `selectDates` and `dateRangeCategory` in the same file? 
   In that case I will have one module with two server functions. Is that allowed?
3. Would it make more sense to handle both operations (setting date range by category and creating `selected_dates`) by the same module server function?
   the result would look like:  `selected_dates <- callModule(dateRangeCategory, "range_and_category")`